# bat script, wait and count to the output

Tags: batch-file

I have some bat scripts where I have to wait for X seconds, currently I am just calling `sleep` which works fine. However, I would like to count to the number that is passed in so I can at least see how long I have left to wait.

But I cannot seem to find how to count to X and output that to the console. Simple I know...

If possible, I would like the numbers to overwrite each other as it counts so that it doesnt fill the screen with numbers.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SLEEP is not a standard Windows command.

If you have a recent version of Windows (ie Vista or better, thanks Neil), you can use the TIMEOUT command (use `TIMEOUT /?` to get help on usage)

The TIMEOUT command does exactly what you are asking for. It counts down the seconds until it reaches 0. The user has the ability to press a key to abort the wait and proceed immediately. The /NOBREAK option disables the ability to skip the wait.

For example, this command will wait for 5 seconds, with a visual countdown.

```
TIMEOUT /T 5
```

Comment: Where "recent" means Vista or better, iirc.